# Variable width depending on position?

Tags: css

If I assign `position:absolute` to an element, its `width` will not be variable depending on the text inside.

On the other hand, if I assign `position:relative` to that element, the `width` will vary depending on the text inside.

Here I have the fiddle with two menus, each one with a different `position` property:
http://jsfiddle.net/je3PX/4/

What is the cause of this? Why `width` depends on the `position` attribute? 
Im looking to make it vary depending on the text size.

Thanks.

Comment: I know this isn't answering your question, but if you need absolute positioning but don't want text to wrap you could use `white-space: nowrap` on `.floatingMenu`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default value for `width` is `auto`, meaning it will adapt itself to the layout as required. For block level elements (`display:block` et al) this means adapting to the parent container, for inline elements (`display:inline` et al) this means adapting to the content.

The `position` attribute factors in this in that the value `relative` does **not** take the element out of the regular flow layout, and as such the base rules are still maintained. The value `absolute` does take it out of the regular flow layout, as such there is no longer a parent to base the width on, as such falling back to fit-to-content.

The relevant rules are defined in [chapter 10 of the W3 CSS2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) (too long to quote).

Comment: +1 Great explanation. But..which would be then the solution the for floating menus which are so common nowadays?

Comment: Well, in the end you have 2 choices - let the browser shrink-to-fit, or specify a fixed width. There's no other viable option available for something that doesn't have relational layout. That's also how all dropdowns I've ever inspected work. If you need something specific you could ask a question on whether it's possible

Comment: I ended up using the `white-space: nowrap` which @jasonmerino named. It seems to do the job.

Comment: It does because it forces the content to be wider, and as such the shrink-to-fit behaviour has to take it into account.